# Storing java objects online

Tags: java, io

this is my first question on stack overflow, I hope you can help me. I've done a bit of searching online but I keep finding tutorials or answers that talk about reading either text files using a BufferedReader or reading bytes from files on the internet. Ideally, I'd like to have a file on my server called "http://ascistudent.com/scores.data" that stores all of the Score objects made by players of a game I have made.

The game is a simple "block-dropping" game where you try to get 3 of the same blocks touching do increase the score. When time runs out, the scores are loaded from a file, their score is added in the right position of a List of Score objects. After that the scores are saved again to the same file.

At the moment I get an exception, **java.io.EOFException** on the highlighted line:

```
URL url   = new URL("http://ascistudent.com/scores.data");
InputStream is = url.openStream();
Score s;
ObjectInputStream load;
//if(is.available()==0)return;
load = new ObjectInputStream(is); //----------java.io.EOFException
while ((s = (Score)load.readObject()) != null){
    scores.add(s);
}
load.close();
```

I suspect that this is due to the file being empty. But then when I catch this exception and tell it to write to the file anyway (after changing the Score List) with the following code, nothing appears to be written (the exception continues to happen.)

```
URL url  = new URL("http://ascistudent.com/scores.data");
URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
ucon.setDoInput(true);
ucon.setDoOutput(true);
os = ucon.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
for(Score s:scores){
    save.writeObject(s);    
}
save.close();
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks very much,
Luke

Comment: Have you considered using a printwriter on it instead and printing it to the console to verify it actually has data?

Comment: You really ought to be doing this sort of thing in a database, specifically some sort of RDBMS (not a filesystem _you_ are maintaining).  For one thing, the performance is going to be way better.  Also, you're not going to have to worry about phantom writes _quite_ as much  (think about this - what happens if two people report their score at the same time?).  Your webhost probably comes with mySQL, although there are other options available (for something this size, you could probably get away with an in-memory implementation).

Comment: You can't write to a file using HTTP. If you could do that, everybody would be able to write to all the files on every web server.

Comment: @X-Zero Yes this is the way to go. Avoid the headache and use a database!

Comment: @JBNizet It *can* be done with a server that understands it. See [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), for instance.

Comment: @pst: of course, but I doubt this is the setup of the OP.

Comment: Databasing seems to be the right option for me. Thanks for the help, what a warm welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively you can't write to an URLConnection unless that connection is writable.

What I mean is that you cannot direcly write to an URL unless the otherside accept what you are going to send. This in HTTP is done throug a POST request that attaches data from your client to the request itself.

On the server side you'll have to accept this post request, take the data and add it tothe scores.data. You can't directly write to the file, you need to process the request in the webserver, eg:

```
http://host/scores.data
```

provides the data, while

```
http://host/uploadscores
```

should be a different URL that accepts a POST request, process it and remotely modifies score.data

Comment: Oh I see! I'll use http requests in that case and php files with a MySQL database to hold the scores. What is the best way to use http requests within java?

Comment: The way you are already doing works fine, you justneed to have an endpoint that works with the post data you send..

Comment: Will that have to be a java server-side program that accepts data and saves it to the file? I don't think my provider supports server-side.

Comment: How about uploading your file to a FTP server?